# Qt – How to add calculated column in QsqlRelationalTableModel?

Tags: qt

I have an table view showed

part description, quantity, price

And I have a Model/View using this code

```
model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this);
model->setTable("parts");
model->setRelation(3,QSqlRelation("part_tbl","part_id","part_desc"));

model->select();
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

I need to add a new column that shows quantity * price in the table view. It's important to know I'm using  QsqlRelationalTableModel

Help is appreciated, Thanks in advance

Comment: @user289175: Did you see Qt Demo example *Relational Table Model Example*?

Comment: Yes, I see it. But the example doesn't answer my question.
Let's reexplain my example again.
I have a database table has four columns
part_id
part_desc related to part_tbl
price
-quantity

I need to to add a virtual column thats display price (multiply) the quantity as a total

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet for handling this is to make either a model that inherits QSqlRelationalTableModel, or one that acts as a proxy (and contains a member for the model).  Your new model will add the extra column, and when the data is requested for that column, use the data from the other columns to compute what is required.

Comment: At first, I would like to send a big thanks for you.
In fact I'm trying to solve this issue using long way. I have created an empty column in the database called it total, now I'm trying programmability to add the two columns into the empty  column. Many thanks again for your help.

Comment: OP, Did this solve your issue? I have a similar problem. I've created the proxy model, the extra column in it, but I cannot set the data for it.